# Which algorithms do IOTA use?

Tags: algorithm

Is there a high-level overview of the different algorithms used by IOTA available somewhere?

My assumption is that there are different algorithms used for signing bundles, creating addresses, sending transactions, tip selection, using MAM and so on.

I've done some searching but have only found some code examples on GitHub and articles about the switch from Curl-P to Keccak. Was hoping someone could point me to a complete list of algorithms used by IOTA and what they are used for.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/2387

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this is the state:
https://github.com/iotaledger/kerl

MAM used troika: https://github.com/iotaledger/entangled/tree/develop/mam

There is a change on the roadmap. We will change to WOTS and asymmetric signatures. (Ed25519 is in discussion): https://blog.iota.org/end-of-year-dev-update-roadmap-for-2020-c106be92305 & https://iota.cafe/t/hybrid-signatures-combining-wots-with-hashed-public-keys/284